# What is the number next to the ip address in wsgi ('127.0.0.1', THE_NUMBER_HERE) and how would I access it?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, wsgi

I'm not the best at phrasing this or thinking of how to phrase it, but bear with me on this.

When I am running a Flask app with SocketIO, I get the following message whenever a connection is made to the server:

```
(5555) wsgi accepted ('127.0.0.1', 12345)
```

I know the (5555) is the process number and that 127.0.0.1 is the IP Address, but what is the 12345 number next to the IP Address?  Is there any way I can access this at all in code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)

Comment: In the source code though, I set the port to run on as port 5000.  So I assume it is a redirect port?

Comment: Both ends need a port number.

Answer (score 0):

This is the port that the connection is open on. If this is a website running through Flask, you can access the page in your browser by going to http://127.0.0.1:12345

Comment: In the source code though, I set the port to 5000.  So I would be accessing it via http://127.0.0.1:5000.  So does that mean SocketIO is binding to that port and redirecting traffic?

Comment: It is the port the process is communicating on, but it is not the port that the process originally listened on to accept the connection. When a connection is accepted on the listener port, that specific session gets a unique port for further communication. You should not be able to visit the second port with a new browser connection as it is not a listener port and so wouldn't accept a connection on it.

Comment: Suggest reading through this series of posts to understand how web servers work. https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/